# Codename One - SpinnerNode - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm using Codename One and in my code I use a DatePicker:

datePicker = new Picker();

In the Simulator, when I attempt to choose a new date, using the picker, an exception is generated (see below). Is there anything I can do to avoid the exception?

```
[EDT] 0:3:5,244 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Index out of bounds:13, must be between 0 and 13
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index out of bounds:13, must be between 0 and 13
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.SpinnerNode.setSelectedIndex(SpinnerNode.java:210)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.SpinnerNode.rebuildChildren(SpinnerNode.java:149)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.SpinnerNode.setRowFormatter(SpinnerNode.java:124)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Spinner3D.setRowFormatter(Spinner3D.java:351)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.DateSpinner3D.initSpinner(DateSpinner3D.java:116)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.DateSpinner3D.<init>(DateSpinner3D.java:90)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker$1.createDatePicker3D(Picker.java:498)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker$1.showInteractionDialog(Picker.java:623)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker$1.actionPerformed(Picker.java:313)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:362)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5265)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: Are you using maven?
Which version is set in the pom.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven. Here's a list of all the versions in the pom.xml file (I'm unsure which you needed). <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT
  <cn1.plugin.version>7.0.92
  <cn1.version>7.0.92
  <java.version>1.8
  <java-tests.version>11
  <rhino.version>1.7.11
  <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0
  <version>3.0.0
  <version>3.0.0-M5
There looks to have been a recent change to SpinnerNode, that might be the cause. https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/3659

Comment: It's the cn1 version but not the plugin version. I guess it says LATEST which is good and you should keep it that way. But to see if this is caused by a specific change try setting that to 7.0.89 just to experiment and see if this works around the problem. Let me know and we'll do a proper fix.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I took a copy of the project in NetBeans, edited the pom.xml (<cn1.version>7.0.89) and yes, in the Simulator, the DatePicker now works as intended - i.e. opens a calendar and I can select a different date).

Comment: I also have this issue in ant. Where to check the cn1.version in ant?

Comment: @DanielTsai You can't change the version in Ant.

Comment: @stylsy we're looking into this.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I've updated to version 7.0.93 and all seems ok. Thanks.